# KendoUI: Get the name of the last view

Tags: kendo-ui

I would like to get the id of the last view in KendoUI. I already inspected the `event` object but found nothing that reveals this.

This could be the view that I came from with a tap or the view that I came from with the back button.

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
var id = $('[data-role=view]:last').attr('id');
```

Comment: this is not doing what I want. This is getting me the id of the last view in the file, not the id of the last shown view.

Answer (score 1):

**This answer is for Kendo UI Mobile applications**, but the basic principal could be used as a basis for a solution for Kendo UI Desktop as well.

I was using `e.view.nextViewID` in the show event handler of my views to get the previous view but this stopped working with kendo ui version 2014.1.528. So, I've figured out the following work-around that uses the [pane.navigate](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/mobile/pane#events-navigate) event to store the previous view in a global variable:

```
var previousView = '';
var app = new kendo.mobile.Application();
app.pane.bind("navigate",
    function(e) {
        previousView = e.sender.view().id;
    }
);
```

I also found that app.pane can be undefined at first so I have wrapped the above call to app.pane.bind in [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) with a delay of 50ms - if there's an official way to know when app.pane is set please share.

Answer (score 1):

To improve the answer above slightly, one can attach events to the app's pane object directly at initalization of the application object, so one does not need the timeout because the app's init fires a tad too early.

```
var previous_view = '';
function store_previous_view(e)
{
    try
    {
        previous_view = e.sender.view().id;
    }
    catch(e){}
}
app = new kendo.mobile.Application({navigate: store_previous_view});
```

The try-catch is there because the event will fire immediately and view() will return null at the very first time. So one should check the value of previous_view for sanity before using it.

This works in Kendo UI core 2014.3.1119. I don't know if it is a loophole or intended behaviour, it's definitely not documented.